# SWT - How do I create two composites within a wizard

Tags: java, swt, jface, composite

I have several composites in my class for a different purpose and I have placed controls into them. My problem is I need a composite on the right hand side of my page which is separated by a border, the right hand side composite needs to be in a rectangle shape filling the wizard vertically where I just display few hyperlinks. Any help will be appreciated. And also the color green covers my label text and text does not show up at all, How do I resolve this?

I could not post any images since I have only 6 reputations and I'm relatively new to StackOverflow. If I could gain 10 reputations then I would be more than happy to post a screen shot.

Here's my code :

```
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
Display device = Display.getCurrent ();
Composite top = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
top.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));

Composite topCompo = new Composite(top, SWT.BORDER);
topCompo.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL)); 
Label label = new Label(topCompo, SWT.BORDER); 
label.setText("Before you continue the person must have a first name and a last name");
RGB rgb = new RGB(183,240,194);
Color color = new Color(device,rgb);
topCompo.setBackground(color);


Composite left = new Composite(top, SWT.NONE);
left.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));

Label label1 = new Label(left, SWT.NONE);
label1.setText("First Name");
text1 = new Text(left, SWT.BORDER);
text1.setText("");

Label label2 = new Label(left, SWT.NONE);
label2.setText("Last Name");
text2 = new Text(left, SWT.BORDER);
text2.setText("");

Label label3 = new Label(left, SWT.FILL);
label3.setText("Positions");
Combo combo = new Combo (left, SWT.READ_ONLY);
combo.setItems (new String [] {"White Position","No Position"});
combo.select(0);

 Composite leftRadio = new Composite(top, SWT.NONE);
 leftRadio.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,true));

 Label label4 = new Label(leftRadio, SWT.FILL);
 label4.setText("Physician Indicator:");

 Button b = new Button(leftRadio, SWT.RADIO);
 b.setText("Yes");
 b.setSelection(true);
 new Button(leftRadio, SWT.RADIO).setText("No");


 Label addrLabel = new Label(leftRadio, SWT.BOLD);
 addrLabel.setFont( new Font(device," ", 9, SWT.BOLD));
 addrLabel.setText("Addresses");

 Composite right = new Composite(parent,SWT.BORDER|SWT.RIGHT);
 right.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
 new Button(right, SWT.RADIO).setText("No");



 Composite tableParent = new Composite(top, SWT.NONE);
 tableParent.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));

 TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(tableParent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
          | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
 final Table table = viewer.getTable();
 table.setHeaderVisible(true);
 table.setLinesVisible(true); 
 viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

 TableViewerColumn colType = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
 colType.getColumn().setWidth(100);
 colType.getColumn().setText("Type");

 TableViewerColumn colStreet = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
 colStreet.getColumn().setWidth(200);
 colStreet.getColumn().setText("Street"); 

 TableViewerColumn colCity = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
 colCity.getColumn().setWidth(150);
 colCity.getColumn().setText("City"); 

 TableViewerColumn colState = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
 colState.getColumn().setWidth(130);
 colState.getColumn().setText("State"); 

 TableViewerColumn colZIPCode = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
 colZIPCode.getColumn().setWidth(130);
 colZIPCode.getColumn().setText("Zip Code"); 

 Composite buttons = new Composite(top, SWT.NONE);
 buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));
 new Button(buttons, SWT.NONE).setText("Add");   
 Button b2 = new Button(buttons, SWT.NONE);
 b2.setText("Remove");
 b2.setEnabled(false);

 text2.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  }
  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
      setPageComplete(true);

    }
  } 

});
setControl(top);
setPageComplete(false);
color.dispose();
}
```

I need a separate composite on the right hand side which would just be a small one in a rectangle shape and it should fill the page vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used a parent composite which has three columns and its 3 child composites which would be divided into 3 columns in a wizard with a separator and it worked perfectly and I seem to get hang of GridLayout and GridData too.